# Error while uploading image file in PHP

Tags: php

i have a problem when uploading file.
when i use variables in directory,
php make a duplicate file: one in correct directory and other in directory before variable.
and this is code i wrote

```
    $ext = $_POST["ext"];
    $evnm = $_POST["evnm"];
    $uploaddir = '../../../media/';
    if (!file_exists($uploaddir)) {
        mkdir($uploaddir, 0777, true);
    }
    $uploaddir .= $evnm.'/';
    if (!file_exists($uploaddir)) {
        mkdir($uploaddir, 0777, true);
    }
    $uploaddir .= $ext.'/';
    if (!file_exists($uploaddir)) {
        mkdir($uploaddir, 0777, true);
    }
    $fl = $_FILES["file"];
    foreach($fl["name"] as $key=>$name){
        $tmp_name = $fl["tmp_name"][$key];
        $targetFile = $uploaddir.$name;
        $files[] = $targetFile;
        if(!file_exists($targetFile)){
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $targetFile)){
                $MSG = "Media file uploaded successfully<br>";
                $tst = true;
            }else{
                $MSG = "Media file failed uploding<br>";
                $tst = false;
            }
        }else{
            $MSG = 'Media file already exists<br>';
            $tst = false;
            $exst = true;
        }
    }
```

`

[image: image shows problem]

Comment: Are you sure `$ext` or `$evnm` vars are empty or not ?

Comment: Instead of multiple `mkdir()` calls, use the `$recursive` argument to `mkdir()` to make all the directories at once.

Comment: I don't see any way this code could be creating files in different directories. The duplicate must be happening somewhere else.

Comment: vars are not empty